# If dataframe.tail(1) is X, do something

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check if the last cell in a pandas data-frame column contains a 1 or a 2 (these are the only options). If it is a 1, I would like to delete the whole row, if it is a 2 however I would like to keep it.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,1,2,1], 'name': ['bill','mary','john','sarah','tom']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,1,2,1,2], 'name': ['bill','mary','john','sarah','tom','sam']})
```

In the above example I would want to delete the last row of df1 (so the final row is 'sarah'), however in df2 I would want to keep it exactly as it is.

So far, I have thought to try the following but I am getting an error

```
if df1['number'].tail(1) == 1:
    df = df.drop(-1)
```

Comment: what would that error be?

Comment: The error I get back is: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: @DC_Liv that is because `tail` returns a Series and so "Series == 1" returns a Boolean Series. Though it's guaranteed to only have a single element, `pd.Series(True)` is not a simple `True` or `False`, which is the only thing that you can use to evaluate an `if` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the value of `number` in the last row is equal to one:

```
check = df1['number'].tail(1).values == 1
# Or check entire row with
# check = 1 in df1.tail(1).values
```

If that condition holds, you can select all rows, except the last one and assign back to `df1`:

```
if check:
   df1 = df1.iloc[:-1, :]
```

Comment: `df1.tail(1).values` will check against all columns

Answer (score 4):

`DataFrame.drop` removes rows based on **labels** (the actual values of the indices). While it is possible to do with `df1.drop(df1.index[-1])` this is problematic with a duplicated index. The last row can be selected with `iloc`, or a single value with `.iat`

```
if df1['number'].iat[-1] == 1:
    df1 = df1.iloc[:-1, :]
```

Comment: I used `df['number'].iat[-1]`.  In my experience, it is very fast to access a column so this use of chained `__getitem__` isn't problematic.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if df1.tail(1).number == 1:
    df1.drop(len(df1)-1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: `df1.drop(-1)` ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the same tail function

```
df.drop(df.tail(n).index,inplace=True) # drop last n rows
```